# Create a device to detect object and voice alert what kind of object it is

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

Here is what I want to do (since I'm not a embedded guy)

- create a prototype with an Arduino to detect objects using camera(object classification?)
- that prototype will detect objects and alert that object's name

My questions are....

- Is it possible? :)
- What things should I use to create a prototype?
- What camera should I use?
- Is it related to image processing?
- Connection between object detection and voice alert?

Comment: I don't think arduino is sufficient for this. Maybe with camera which can detects objects itself and voice recognition module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino is not the ideal platform for you since it is more "lightweight" and can't really meet the demand that your application is expecting.

A platform like for example Raspberry Pi that has a full-blown operating system and a lot of tools that fulfils your application needs.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!!